# XlsxWriter autofilter oldest to newest date Django/Python

Tags: python, django, excel, xlsxwriter

Does anyone knows how can I set up a cell to filter the date from the oldest to the newest using XlsxWriter?

I have checked the XlsxWriter documentation, but there is nothing straight on that. I can upload my code if is needed.

Than you for your time.

Comment: Ordering the data is more of a Sorting requirement than a Filtering requirement. The Excel file format doesn't support Sorting; this is done at runtime within the application. Instead you should sort your data in Python/Django and then write it an Excel file with XlsxWriter.

Comment: omg, good point ! didn't thought that way !

Comment: With your advice I used Reporte3a5.objects.filter().order_by('target_pdate', 'target_fcd_date') and it worked. Thanks !